# How to install Peatio on cPanel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, git

Intro : Peatio is a free and open-source crypto currency exchange implementation with the Rails framework and other cutting-edge technology.

We want to install Peatio in cPanel but we didn't found any tutorial or any article how can we install this on cPanel . I found their wiki and their is only linux/Mac and Ubuntu installation guides available. We opened issue and thought they maybe help us and they refer us to post on stack overflow. I hope someone help us. And i am also willing to pay , we have root access on our cPanel server. 
Github Link is [here](https://github.com/peatio/peatio)

> Requirements
>
> Linux / Mac OSX Ruby 2.1.0 Rails 4.0+ Git 1.7.10+ Redis 2.0+ MySQL
>   RabbitMQ

Thank you.

Comment: did y read https://github.com/peatio/peatio#getting-started

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio yes we read this but didn't found this cPanel related .

Answer (score 1):

Peatio is Ruby based exchange which can not installed on cPanel but any one can use this repository: https://github.com/saydulk/peatio

Requirements For Setup:
VPS: digitalocean.com
OS: Debian 9
RAM: Min 8GB Recommended 16
Domain: Any top level domain name